# Replace each letter with it's ASCII code in a string in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, ascii

is a better, shorter way to preform this code:

```
/*Replace all letters by their respective ASCII code - 55*/
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'A', '10');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'B', '11');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'C', '12');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'D', '13');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'E', '14');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'F', '15');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'G', '16');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'H', '17');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'I', '18');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'J', '19');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'K', '20');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'L', '21');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'M', '22');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'N', '23');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'O', '24');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'P', '25');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'Q', '26');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'R', '27');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'S', '28');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'T', '29');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'U', '30');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'V', '31');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'W', '32');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'X', '33');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'Y', '34');
as_iban := REPLACE(as_iban, 'Z', '35');
```

The code above converts all the upper chars of the string to there respective ASCII code numbers. but this is not the correct way of going about it, but I can't figure out another way of doing it.

I have tried something like

```
FOR i in 1..LENGTH(as_iban)
LOOP
select regexp_replace(as_iban,'['||substr(as_iban,i,1)||']', ASCII(regexp_substr(as_iban,'['||substr(as_iban,i,1)||']')) - 55) into as_iban FROM dual;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: [First hit on Google](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions013.htm#SQLRF00604) for "Oracle PL/SQL ASCII function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUBAR_STR(in_str VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  out_str VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(in_str) LOOP
    out_str := out_str || TO_CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTR(in_str,i,1)) - 55);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN out_str;
END FUBAR_STR;
```

So when you run:

```
select fubar_str('abcd') from dual;
```

You get: 42434445.

Here is the reversible, safer one to use.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUBAR_STR(in_str VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  out_str VARCHAR2(32676) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..LEAST(LENGTH(in_str),10892) LOOP
    out_str := out_str || LPAD(TO_CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTR(in_str,i,1)) - 55),3,'0');
  END LOOP;
  RETURN out_str;
END FUBAR_STR;
```

So when you run:

```
select fubar_str('abcd') from dual;
```

You get: 042043044045.

And because I'm really bored tonight:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNFUBAR_STR(in_str VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  out_str VARCHAR2(10892) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0..(((LENGTH(in_str) - MOD(LENGTH(in_str),3))/3) - 1) LOOP
    out_str := out_str || CHR(TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(SUBSTR(in_str,(i * 3) + 1,3),'0')) + 55);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN out_str;
END UNFUBAR_STR;
```

So when you run:

```
select unfubar_str('042043044045') from dual;
```

You get: abcd.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in one command:

```
select listagg((column_value).getstringval() - 55) 
within group (order by 1) as output
from xmltable(regexp_replace(dump('abcd'), '.*: (\d.*)$', '\1'));
```

Output:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Explanation:

Take the output from `dump()` and use `regexp_replace()` to extract the comma-separated list of ASCII values from the output (Dump output includes a comma-separated list of ASCII values of the data passed in).  Use `xmltable()` to turn that comma-separated list into rows.  This is needed because we need to then process each row, subtracting 55 from the value per the requirement, using `listagg()` to turn the result after subtracting 55  into one string.

For more info, see:

dump(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635
regexp_replace(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302
xmltable(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions240.htm#SQLRF06232
listagg(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030