# Is it possible to convert strings like 'John' and 'Jane' to numeric values but keep them readable as 'John' and 'Jane'

Tags: sql, oracle

Question is all in the title.  I am trying to Union two blocks, one is numeric and one is a string.  I understand that you can't union those together.  Converting all my numbers to text is doable, but not ideal because then my output is text instead of numeric.  My question is: is it possible to do the opposite of that, convert the text fields into numeric values but keep them readable as 'John' and 'Jane'.

Comment: Looks like you want translation table `name | numeric value`

Comment: @lad2025 ur reputation is cool. 55,555...

Comment: binary and octal are numeric. You could implement a function to convert you string to either one of those. Or you could [implement a function like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375773/replace-each-letter-with-its-ascii-code-in-a-string-in-pl-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to have it spit out the ASCII character codes for the string (assuming no unicode here).

Comment: Ultimately though they won't be "Readable" until they are converted back. There is no way around that unless you convert them to some numeric only 1337 speak. I'm also thinking you'll want an indicator in your UNION output to tell you whether it's text converted to numeric or just a boring old number for translating it back when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Use base 62 instead of decimal. With base 62 you can use all your letters (lower case and upper case) as numbers.

```
0 - 0
...
9 - 9
a - 10
...
z - 35
A - 36
...
Z - 62
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: In this example I would have to convert the base 62 back to text to write out full words though, correct?

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you're going about this wrong. You don't say enough about your application, but you're trying to union together a text and numeric column. I'm imagining something like this:

```
SELECT t1.my_numeric_column
  FROM mytable1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.my_varchar2_column
  FROM mytable2 t2
```

And as you say, this doesn't work. What you should be doing is this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( t1.my_numeric_column )
  FROM mytable1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.my_varchar2_column
  FROM mytable2 t2
```

You say this is "not ideal because then my output is text instead of numeric", but if you're displaying this text somewhere (and you don't say where or how), then your output *is* text, not numeric.

Either that or the problem that you're trying to solve isn't well defined here.